# Unable to use Storage plugin in amplify: Plugin category does not exist

Tags: swift, aws-amplify

When trying to add the Auth plugin and the storage plugin as follow inside the app delegate:

```
 private func setupAWS() {
        do {
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSS3StoragePlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
         
            print("Amplify configured with storage plugin")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to initialize Amplify with \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Im getting a problem with the storage plugin, which is preventing me from doing image uploads:

```
Failed to initialize Amplify with PluginError: Plugin category does not exist.
Recovery suggestion: Verify that the library version is correct and supports the plugin's category.
```

the pod file contains the following pods:

```
 pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSS3StoragePlugin’
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Can you see that the storage plugin has been added on the amplify console?

Comment: I don't have an amplify console.
this happened when I uploaded the amplify pods to the latest version